# Git fast-forward merge to preserve original committer and committer date

Tags: git, git-merge, fast-forward

While I'm doing something like

```
git merge --ff-only someBranch
```

author and author date are nicely preserved, but committer and committer date are overwritten.

How can I do fast-forward merge and preserve original committer and committer date?

[Documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) doesn't help at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *fast-forward* merge does not do any actual merging: It neither introduces a new merge commit, nor does it touch any of the existing commits (that would be a rebase, which can be a harmful operation). Instead, a fast-forward merge *only* changes the current branch pointer to the target commit.

So in your case, when you do `git merge --ff-only someBranch`, your current branch, e.g. `master` will be changed to point at the same commit that `someBranch` points at. The `--ff-only` option prevents Git from performing an actual merge, so it won’t create a merge commit there but only ever fast-forward.

This should not change the commit at all, and preserve *every* property of the commits. If you see a different committer for commits you merged with `--ff-only`, then they had those values already before merging them.

Comment: Thanks a lot and you are obviously right. The operation that changes committer and committer date in my case apparently is `git rebase` - how can I avoid that?

Comment: I’m afraid the answer is: don’t rebase. Rebasing changes the commits, and creates new ones that are incompatible with the original, so you should avoid doing that anyway.